# Bayes theorem and three shooters

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Three shooters $A,B,C$ aim at a target. Each of them shoots one. The accuracy of the $A$ shooter is equal to $0.6$, $B$ is $0.7$, $C$ is $0.8$. What's the probability that $A$ hit the target if:

1. the target was hit once,
2. the target was hit twice,
3. the target was hit at least once,
4. the target was hit at least twice.

It's obvious that
$$ P(A)=0.6$$
$$P(B)=0.7$$
$$ P(C)=0.6$$
where $P(\cdot)$ is the probability that the shooter hit the target.

For 1) I have:
$$P(A|T_{1})=\frac{P(T_{1}|A)\cdot P(A)}{P(T_{1}|A)\cdot P(A) + P(T_{1}|B)\cdot P(B) + P(T_{1}|C)\cdot P(C)} $$
where $P(T_{1}|A)=0.6*(1-0.7)*(1-0.8)$ and respectively for the other ones.

For 2)
$$P(A|T_{2})=\frac{P(T_{2}|A\cap B)\cdot P(A \cap B) + P(T_{2}|A\cap C)\cdot P(A \cap C)}{...}$$
Now, I'm kind of lost. What I wanted to obtain is the probability that A hit the target and the target was hit twice - so either B or C can aim with A. But what's $P(A \cap B)$? Maybe I want $P(A \cup B)$?

For 3)
My first thought was to make this with the opposite event. So the target wasn't hit at all. But I can't imagine how to appy Bayes theorem to this case. I mean if the target wasn't hit then the probability that A hit the target is 0. Something doesn't feel right. For 4) I have a similar problem.

Comment: "Accuracy" might mean probability, but it might also mean something different. But assuming that it does, here are some comments. (1) In your first equation, what you write as "$\mathrm{P}(T_1|A)$" more precisely is $\mathrm{P}(T_1|A \land \lnot B \land \lnot C)$, and similarly for other terms, where $A :={}$"Shooter A hits". (2) From the statement of the problem it seems that we can judge the probabilites of individual hits to be independent, so $\mathrm{P}(A \land B) = \mathrm{P}(A) \cdot \mathrm{P}(B)$ and so on – note that you're indeed assuming this in your calculation of "$P(T_1|A)$".

Comment: But you seem to be on the right track! In this case a simple logical enumeration or decomposition can be done, and is also instructive. So for example $T_1 \equiv (A \land \lnot B \land \lnot C) \lor (\lnot A \land B \land \lnot C) \lor (\lnot A \land \lnot B \land C)$, and similarly for $T_2$, $T_{>0}$, etc. Then you just have to mechanically apply the rules for logical connectives and the three probability rules.

Comment: Your intuition for 3) is also correct, you're saying that $T_{>0} \equiv \lnot T_0$, so $\mathrm{P}(T_{>0}|A) = \mathrm{P}(\lnot T_{0}|A) = 1- \mathrm{P}(\lnot A \land \lnot B\land \lnot C|A) =1-0=1$, which makes logical sense. Similarly for the conditional on the other two. Then you can apply Bayes's theorem again.

Comment: Thanks, when you put it like this it makes much more sense, I mean it's more explicitly written :)

Comment: I recommend you take a look at this book: https://archive.org/details/XQUHIUXHIQUHIQXUIHX2 or http://www-biba.inrialpes.fr/Jaynes/prob.html It guides you through the logical passages in problems like these, and gives many deep insights :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First question:**

$$\mathbb{P}[A|\text{1 hit}]=\frac{\mathbb{P}[A]\mathbb{P}[\overline{B}]\mathbb{P}[\overline{C}]}{\mathbb{P}[A]\mathbb{P}[\overline{B}]\mathbb{P}[\overline{C}]+\mathbb{P}[\overline{A}]\mathbb{P}[B]\mathbb{P}[\overline{C}]+\mathbb{P}[\overline{A}]\mathbb{P}[\overline{B}]\mathbb{P}[C]}=\frac{36}{36+56+96}=\frac{9}{47}$$

**Second question:**

Consider that if the target was hit twice the following cases are possible

$$AB,AC,BC$$

Thus the solution is very similar to 1)

$$\mathbb{P}[A|\text{2 hits}]=\frac{0.6\times0.7\times0.2+0.6\times0.3\times0.8}{0.6\times0.7\times0.2+0.6\times0.3\times0.8+0.4\times0.7\times0.8}=\frac{228}{452}=\frac{57}{113}$$

**Third question**:

$$\mathbb{P}[A|\text{hits} \geq 1]=\frac{36+228+336}{1000-24}=\frac{75}{122}$$

**Fourth question**:

It is up to you...

---

To speed up the calculation of 3. I used the numerators previously calculated, which are the favourable cases with 1 and 2 hits, respectively.

I used integer numbers because I do not like decimals...

Comment: Why in Bayes theorem in the numerator you have $P(A)P(\overline{B})P(\overline{C})$ ? I mean I've been taught that it look more like $P(A|B)\cdot P(B)$. It makes sense to me but I don't know why it is like that.

Comment: @Awerde : even if not explicitly stated, I assumed that the "accuracy" of the 3 shooters is independent Thus $P(A|B)=P(A)$. This is a simply Conditional Probability

Comment: Right, I forgot about this! Thanks a lot ;)